# Simple Seneca Promises Example

Tags: node.js, bluebird, seneca

I am trying to use Bluebird with Seneca in order to promisfy all my seneca modules that I create. I'd love to be able to chain seneca commands.

Here is a transaction module which to make things as simple as possible, only has one task, to create a transaction

```
// ./app/transaction.js

module.exports = function(options) {
  var Promise = require('bluebird');
  var seneca = this;
  var act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, {context: seneca});

  var Transaction = require('./models/transaction');

  this.add({role:'transaction', cmd: 'create'}, function( msg, done ) {
    var t = new Transaction({
      datetime: new Date(),
      stylist_ids: ["STY_001", "STY_002"],
      promoter_ids: ["HOT_001", "HOT_002"],
      amount: 100
    });

    t.save((err,transaction) => {
      if (err)
        done(err);
      else
        done(null, { transaction: transaction });
    });
  })
}
```

And here is my code for server.js which at present should just create a transaction using seneca commands:

```
// server.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/promisfy");

var seneca = require('seneca')();
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, seneca);

var transaction = require ('./app/transaction');
seneca.use(transaction);

act({role:'transaction', cmd: 'create'})
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ge' of undefined
    at do_act (/Users/jackrobson/development/active/glam-army-admin-app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:1046:30)
    at Object.api_act (/Users/jackrobson/development/active/glam-army-admin-app/node_modules/seneca/seneca.js:867:5)
    at Object.tryCatcher (/Users/jackrobson/development/active/glam-army-admin-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at ret (eval at makeNodePromisifiedEval (/Users/jackrobson/development/active/glam-army-admin-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promisify.js:184:12), <anonymous>:14:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jackrobson/development/active/glam-army-admin-app/server.js:11:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

"Note that Bluebird v3 has some promisification API changes. Instead of

```
var act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, seneca);
```

we have to use

```
var act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, {context: seneca});"
```

server.js had the old command -_-''